# X509Certificate2.Verify() with moved clock returns false

Tags: c#, security, x509certificate2

As far as I understand, my certificate should be valid at any time, as long as it was signed before April 2014 (while signing, we do put timestamp).

If I calling `X509Certificate2.Verify()` on my signed assembly, it returns `true`.

However, if I move my computer's clock forward, to say 2019 - calling `X509Certificate2.Verify()` returns `false`. This is unexpected, since I thought it still should be valid.

Could anyone explain me this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Strange - whenever I've created certificate, I had to enter for how long it is valid. I bet yours certificate has expiration too. Check it out for example here - http://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html

Comment: @ Ondrej Svejdar: If I moving clock forward and then looking to properties of the certificate (you know, right click on file -> properties) - I see everything "valid". However, "Verify" method returns false...

Comment: Is there an issuing certificate in the certification path that has an expiration date before 2019?  [RFC 5280 section 6.1.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-6.1.3) requires each certificate in the certification path be currently valid for the certificate to be verified.

Comment: The signing certificate is valid till April-2014. We assume the signed assembly should have a valid certificate as long as it was signed before that date. AFAIK that is the purpose of the timestamp used when signing.

Comment: This question sounds like it's conflating a code signing signature's validity with the validity of the certificate.  What is the target file when you check File->Properties?  The certificate .cer? The certificate .pfx?  Or some other kind of file?